# Implementing functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, instance

I'm trying to implement an eval function using my own type aliases and data constructor. This function is supposed to return an updated dictionary Dict and program counter Counter according to the Func inputted. Basically, I want it to increment the counter if an input is correct.
These are my type aliases:

```
type Counter = Int
type Name = String
type Dict = Map Name Const
```

This is a type I created to be used in a later the class I mention below:

```
data Func = GET_INT Int
          | GET_DICT Name
          | JUMP Counter
          deriving Show
```

And this is the class with the function and where I'm making Func an instance of it:

```
class Evaluate a where
  eval ::  Func -> (Dict, Counter) -> Maybe (Dict, Counter)
 
instance Evaluate Func where
  eval (GET_INT a)(d, c) = Just(d, c+1)
  eval (GET_DICT a)(d, c) = Just(d, c+1)
  eval (JUMP a)(d, c) = Just(d, c+1)
  eval = Nothing
```

However, I am getting some errors. First of all, I am getting the following: Expected a type, but 'Counter' has kind 'Const'

Secondly, I am not sure I entered the correct parameters for the Evaluate class, as a is not being used anywhere. Also, I don't think the inputs for the function will work as they are above.

Can anyone help figure out how to get the function to work?

Comment: The code you've included doesn't generate that error. There are many, many problems with your code; what you've written makes so little sense it's hard to tell what you're even trying to do. Try breaking this problem down into smaller parts until you get to something small enough you can ask about it with clarity.

Comment: Can you indicate where my first mistake is?

Comment: @m.18: for example you return a 2-tuple, but the signature specifies that the type should be a `Maybe (Dict, Counter)`, so you need to return a `Just ...` that wraps a value, or a `Nothing`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that the return is not correct but I was focusing on the input types since it was giving me an error. Can you spot my mistake in the input arguments?

Comment: @m.18: unless you use an extension (`OverloadedLists`), `[(d1, d2)]` is *not* a `Map`, a `Map` is an object that you can use as specified in the [**`Data.Map.Lazy`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html).

Comment: However, it still doesn't work if I replaced [(d1, d2)] with Map d1 d2

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Could you explain how I can input a Map argument?

Comment: You create it by passing your list of tuples to `Map.fromList`. You can't pattern match on a proper list (the details of how the key/value pairs are actually stored is a hidden implementation detail, but there are plenty of function provided by `Data.Map.Lazy` that cover just about anything you might want to do to or with a `Map`.

Comment: So I edited this line to ` eval (GET_INT a)(fromList [(d1, d2)],c) = Just (fromList [(d1,d2)], c) `  but I'm getting the error 'Parse error in pattern: fromList'

Comment: Can you explain **in plain English** what `eval` should do?

Comment: voting to close due to lack of focus.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. eval is a function that updates Dict and Counter according to Func. (The updating part still has to be implemented)

Comment: A function that does *not* update anything would be for example `eval _ x = Just x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These are my types:

```
type Counter = Int
type Name = String
type Dict = Map Name Int
```

Those are type aliases, but ok.

> This is my dataclass:

```
data Func = GET_INT Int
          | GET_DICT Name
          deriving Show
```

The term "dataclass" doesn't mean anything. Func is a type. There are two data constructors. Ok.

> And this is the class with the function I'm trying to create:

```
class Evaluate a where
  eval ::  a -> (Dict, Counter) -> Maybe (Dict, Counter)
```

Well that doesn't make much sense. What is `eval` and why should it be parameterized by `a`?  I think you'd be better served by just defining `eval :: Func -> (Dict, Counter) -> Maybe (Dict, Counter)` first and thinking hard about why you'd want to make it more polymorphic.

```
eval (GET_INT a)([(d1, d2)],c) = ([(d1,d2)], c)
eval (GET_DICT a)([(d1, d2)],c) = ([(d1,d2)], c)
```

> This is the error I'm getting: Equations for `eval' have different numbers of arguments.

No. With the code you presented this is not the error. You should always provide the actual code used to produce the error causing your confusion.

Actual error number one:

```
so.hs:15:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[(a0, b0)]’ with ‘Map Name Int’
      Expected type: Dict
        Actual type: [(a0, b0)]
    • In the pattern: [(d1, d2)]
      In the pattern: ([(d1, d2)], c)
      In an equation for ‘eval’:
          eval (GET_INT a) ([(d1, d2)], c) = ([(d1, d2)], c)
   |
15 |   eval (GET_INT a)([(d1, d2)],c) = ([(d1,d2)], c)
```

This is because, with small exception, the syntax `[ ... ]` is a list and not a Map. You can not pattern match on maps and should just match a variable such as `env`.

```
so.hs:15:36: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe (Dict, Counter)’
                  with actual type ‘([(a0, b0)], Counter)’
    • In the expression: ([(d1, d2)], c)
      In an equation for ‘eval’:
          eval (GET_INT a) ([(d1, d2)], c) = ([(d1, d2)], c)
      In the instance declaration for ‘Evaluate Func’
    • Relevant bindings include
        d2 :: b0 (bound at so.hs:15:26)
        d1 :: a0 (bound at so.hs:15:22)
   |
15 |   eval (GET_INT a)([(d1, d2)],c) = ([(d1,d2)], c)
```

A tuple of `(a,b)` is not the same as `Maybe (a,b)`. Sadly you evidently already knew this but pasted distracting code - clean up the code prior to asking the question.

If we fix these two issues then we get code that loads fine but is entirely worthless:

```
import Data.Map

type Counter = Int
type Name = String
type Dict = Map Name Int

data Func = GET_INT Int
          | GET_DICT Name
          deriving Show

class Evaluate a where
  eval ::  a -> (Dict, Counter) -> Maybe (Dict, Counter)
 
instance Evaluate Func where
  eval (GET_INT a) (env,c) = Just (env, c)
  eval (GET_DICT a) (env,c) = Just (env, c)
```

Comment: If I were to implement the eval function like this: eval :: Func -> (Dict, Counter) -> Maybe (Dict, Counter) , how can I include the class parameter? As this is what I initially wanted but got confused.

Comment: I have updated the code in the original post in a way my function has purpose. That is, to increment the counter according to the func input. Could you check whether it makes more sense and where I am mistaken?